# Left to Right and Right to Left Design

Tags: html, css, bidi

I am using the Google language API for multi language on my site https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started.  Which is working fine so far.

I want the website orientation from left to right when the user selects the Arabic language.

So I need to check that the user has selected Arabic from the google dropdown which will then trigger a css event to change the page orientation from left to right.

Comment: You may want to use CSS's property: direction

Comment: You can create an `array` of `rtl` languages, and onchange of selectbox, compare value with `array` and add any custom class on `body` with `direction:rtl`

Comment: this is my google api code can you advice how can i change the property of css if some one select arabic from dropdown

Comment: <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
                                                                  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                                                                      new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE }, 'google_translate_element'); }
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use like this  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

refer the link yocan get...

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Comment: Thanks there are two part of the question 1. left to right, thanks for the link https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir now second part is i am using google api on my site like iconnect10.com so when user select arabic, i need to check that user select google api and need to apply the body dir to rtl please advice

Comment: use css to switch right to left .., use class in select option ...,you can make it...     refer the link  below

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `jquery` in your project, this may help, add language value in `lagArray`.

```js
var lagArray = ['ar', 'fa', 'ur']
$('#languageDropDown').on('change', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  for (var i = 0; i < lagArray.length; i++) {
    if ($this.val() === lagArray[i]) {
      $('html').attr('dir','rtl');
      return false
    } else {
      $('html').attr('dir', 'ltr');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.rtl{
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="languageDropDown">
  <option value="am">AMHARIC</option>
  <option value="ar">ARABIC</option>
  <option value="bn">BENGALI</option>
  <option value="zh">CHINESE</option>
  <option value="el">GREEK</option>
  <option value="mr">MARATHI</option>
  <option value="ne">NEPALI</option>
  <option value="or">ORIYA</option>
  <option value="fa">PERSIAN</option>
  <option value="ur">URDU</option>
</select>

<div class="textbox">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, consequuntur eaque eos aliquid dolor natus dolores, commodi cum, reiciendis mollitia autem ex reprehenderit quos fugiat molestias corporis neque tempore aliquam.
</div>
```

**Edit**

This plugin is already adding classes `translated-rtl` and `translated-ltr` on HTML, you can use these classes to set directions.

```
.translated-rtl{
 direction: rtl;
}

.translated-ltr{
 direction: ltr;
}
```

***[Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/TBk2vxyJntRihe7Whw67?p=preview)***